# WPF DataGrid - Assigning DataContext to Row

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row, datacontext

I have a situation where ItemsSource property of a DataGrid is an array of integers. These integers are the keys to a corresponding dictionary. What I need to display in columns are the fields, that are members of the dictionary values objects.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=thisDataContext, ElementName=control, Mode=OneWay}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">                                                
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="0.3*" Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IntToPersonConverter}, Mode=OneWay }"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Department" Width="0.3*" Binding="{Binding Path=DepartmentIDX, Converter={StaticResource DepartmentConverter}, Mode=OneWay }" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position" Width="0.3*" Binding="{Binding Path=EmployeeTypeIDX, Converter={StaticResource EmployeeTypeConverter}, Mode=OneWay }" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>     
</DataGrid>
```

The object of a class Person I'm working with have Properties - Department and Position ids, so I've implemented multiple Converters - Person to Department name and Person to Postition name. I have no idea how to combine all of them. I thought that would be possible if I could set DataContext properties to the DataGrid Rows. So I could pass a Person object to a Convertor.

Comment: What exactly are you using as ItemsSource for you grid - a collection Integers or a collection of Person obejcts (which is implied by your XAML)?

Comment: It's a collection of integers

Comment: then {Binding} is as far as you can go. You XAML implies that you're using objects as opposed to integers anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no much point in exercising WPF futures such as binding converters etc just for the sake of proving that they work - they do. The number of calls to converter is going to be massive, which isn't elegant at least and is easily avoidable. I'd suggest that you pre-process your collection before setting grid's ItemsSource.

I would personally use LINQ projectsions, and establish the dictionaries as static members of your class. Give us a shout and I'll post a sample.

Update 1 - Sample Code

```
public class Person
    {
        private static Dictionary<int, string> Departments;

        static Person()
        {
            Person.SetUpDictionaries();
        }

        private static void SetUpDictionaries()
        {
            Person.Departments = new Dictionary<int, string>(3)
            {
                { 1, "IT" },
                { 1, "Finance" },
                { 1, "HR" }
            };
        }

        public int DepartmentId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Depratment
        {
            get { return Person.Departments[this.DepartmentId]; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouting :)
If you do have a sample code it would be great if you post it here.

Answer (score 2):

If the items collection is a list of keys into a dictionary, you would have to write a converter that converts first dictionary keys to dictionary values, i.e. Person objects and second Person objects to Person property values. To achieve this, the converter must have access to the dictionary. Fortunately there is a way to pass an additional parameter to a WPF value converter, namely the converter parameter in the Convert and ConvertBack methods. Here you could pass the dictionary object and your Convert method could look like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    IDictionary<int, Person> dict = parameter as IDictionary<int, Person>;
    if (dict != null && value is int)
    {
        Person p = dict[(int)value];
        return p.SomeProperty;
    }
}
```

Passing the converter parameter is done by the [ConverterParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter.aspx) property of the binding.

Comment: I have an access to a dictionary in code-behind. What I wanted to achieve is not to search my Person object in the dictionary each time I need to pull some property, but to pass an exact Person object to a convertor instead of id.

Thanks for pointing to ConverterParameter. I've tried to use Binding  to a Person object in ConverterParameter - but it's not possible.